# Programming with Clarity Design

Tags: backend, vmware-clarity, clarity

I'm new in the experience of clarity design use. And I have a mission: To develop a WEB Site using Clarity Design Framework. Additionally, I want to use Angular CLI for to create the "pattern of interface". However, into now, I'm thinking about frontend part.

But I need to understand how I will built the backend part. My Website need to share videos and others static content. And I don't know how to save my contents for correct and simplify management for others people. In short, I need a clue about software for content management, however, with compatibility with Clarity Design. The initial idea is to built a Front-End and... after, to integrate with backend.

Can anybody help with this challenge?

Best regards!

Comment: This is very broad question.  Perhaps you should take few online courses on building Angular applications.  May be this course - https://www.udemy.com/course/angular-2-and-nodejs-the-practical-guide/ - will help you achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, thanks for your help! In fact, my question is very broad. But you understanded my purpose. I saw the course program and it's is sufficient for a first interaction with the Angular. I'll follow your orientation and to study some technologies of backend and Frontend. After some videos and articles, I decided to study this technologies: Mongo, Express, Angular 1 e Node. I finded a Udemy Course wich to teach to build a Application from zero!

Best reagards. See ya.